# Node.js - Can I install NPM package on a PhoneGap / Cordova application?

Tags: mysql, node.js, cordova, npm

I'm building a mobile app thanks to Cordova, and as Cordova is based on Node.js, I thought that I could use NPM packages into the app.

For example, I want my mobile app to talk to a remote MySQL database. I thought I could use the mysql NPM package (https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql) in order to embed a MySQL driver into my mobile app, but I don't see any docs or tutos to install NPM packages into my mobile app.

So, is that possible to "embed" NPM packages into a Cordova app ? Is my app "architecture" bad ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Regards,
Sylvain

Comment: You can use node packages for development purposes like using grunt, bower, etc. but inside the app you have to use phonegap/cordova plugins

Comment: Tanks for your answer, but technically, I don't understand why I can't use node modules. Isn't that only Javascript files ?

Comment: Yes they are js files but they requiere the node.js runtime to work and you cannot install or embed NodeJS on the mobile platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use node packages for development purposes like using grunt, bower, etc. but inside the app you have to use phonegap/cordova plugins.

You cannot use node modules in your phonegap app, because even if they are js files they require the Node.JS runtime to work and you cannot install or embed NodeJS on the mobile platforms.

But you can use any JS library that doesn´t not have a Node dependency, some I have used are moment.js, knockout.js, jquery, backbone.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you say "you cannot use node modules in your phonegap app", but actually you can with this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm).

Answer (score 0):

The statement in your code will fail if you have not included the **sqlite Plugin** in your project.

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "test.db"});
```

Also you should be waiting for the deviceready event to get fired before using cordova plugins.
You can use **window.openDatabase()** call which creates sqlite DB and does not need the sqlite plugin.
Below is the code for using the openDatabase call in you app.

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    // Populate the database
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }
```

The above code snippet is taken from the Cordova API doc. See [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) for details. Even though the documentation is for 3.0 it should work for 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Use the npm package: [`cordova-import-npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm)

> Import files from npm packages into your cordova `www/` directory
> automatically, upon `cordova prepare`, `cordova build` or `cordova run`, and
> before anything else is processed.
>
> Oftentimes we want to import the latest files available in npm
> packages into our `www/` directory in cordova projects. With this module
> you can do it automatically without building your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

[FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518748/integrating-cordova-with-node-js-to-build-mobile-applications)

> Cordova is for interfacing your mobile app's client with that of the
> OS. Nodejs is a server-side technology. You can build both components
> separately... Your cordova mobile app (or native mobile app, or
> whatever), i.e., The Client will talk with your nodejs server, i.e.,
> The Server.

There are a few node modules for cordova apps

**nodejs-mobile-cordova**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mobile-cordova
- https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/getting-started-cordova

**node-cordova**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cordova