# integrating cordova with node js to build mobile applications

Tags: node.js, cordova, mobile-application

Are there any resources for integrating cordova with node-js to build mobile applications.
how to connect nodejs to cordova for building mobile app?

Comment: https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/getting-started-cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova is for interfacing your mobile app's client with that of the OS. Nodejs is a server-side technology. You can build both components separately... Your cordova mobile app (or native mobile app, or whatever), i.e., **The Client** will talk with your nodejs server, i.e., **The Server**.

If you've built cordova apps before, just continue as is, or if you're new, checkout some bootstrap packages like those for [Sencha](http://sensai-touch.com/building-an-ios-and-android-app-with-sencha-touch-2-3-and-cordova/) or [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html) or any of the million other frameworks, or start building your own app from scratch (though it's a little tough to get everything in your head sometimes)

Comment: Thanks Harsh. I'm currently trying with Ionic but still its unable to connect to node.js. Cant i directly connect to server or shall i have to write Web Service for talking to Server?

Comment: What do you mean "directly connect"? Just make your server available at, say, localhost:3000, and make the requests like you do in plain js... it's no different.