# How do I load node_modules in Cordova? (web browser modules, not node.js specific)

Tags: cordova, npm

I have created a new Cordova app using

```
cordova create MyApp
```

I wanted to use a couple of web libraries (no dependency on node.js) and so I installed them with npm. E.g.

```
npm install onsenui vue-onsenui --save-dev
```

The directory structure looks like:

```
config.xml
hooks/
node_modules/
package.json
platforms/
plugins/
res/
www/
```

The index.html file in www has script tags to include the libraries

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="onsenui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vue-onsenui.js"></script>
```

When running the `cordova run browser` command, the web server runs fine and displays the page as it should, including loading the cordova.js file, but it returns 404 for the other libraries.

Is there a way to use these node modules in Cordova without copying them into the www directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24742173/777265 - though if you really want to: https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova

Comment: Ahh good point. The node modules I'm using are just standard web browser ones. E.g. Vue is a framework like Angular. I'll update the question to be more specific.

Comment: check this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TLDR and simple

Use the npm package: [`cordova-import-npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm)

#### Long question and DIY

You can **[use a hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html)** before `cordova prepare`, that is, when the files are assembled for compiling.

1. Edit your `config.xml` and add this line (not inside any platform but in the root, i.e. inside `<widget`):

```xml
<hook src="hooks/importNpmPackages.js" type="before_prepare"/>
```

2. Create the file `hooks/importNpmPackages.js` with this content

```js
const fse = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')
const twoSpaces = '  ' // for log indentation
var projectRoot

module.exports = function (context) {
  console.log(`${context.hook} : ${path.relative(context.opts.projectRoot, context.scriptLocation)}`)

  projectRoot = context.opts.projectRoot
  console.log(twoSpaces + 'Project root directory: ' + projectRoot)

  copyFile('jquery', path.join('dist', 'jquery.min.js'), path.join('js', 'res', 'jquery.min.js'))

  copyFile('bootstrap', path.join('dist', 'js', 'bootstrap.min.js'), path.join('js', 'res', 'bootstrap.min.js'))
  copyFile('bootstrap', path.join('dist', 'css', 'bootstrap.min.css'), path.join('css', 'res', 'bootstrap.min.css'))
}

function copyFile (npmPackage, // oficial name of the npm package from which the file is to be copied from
  fileRelativePath, // file path with respect to the main directory of the npm package (node_modules/<package>/)
  destFilePath) { // file's path to where it is copied, relative to the project www/ directory
  
  const packageDirFullpath = path.dirname(require.resolve(path.join(npmPackage, 'package.json')))
  const fileOriginFullPath = path.join(packageDirFullpath, fileRelativePath)
  const fileDestFullPath = path.join(projectRoot, 'www', destFilePath)

  fse.copySync(fileOriginFullPath, fileDestFullPath)

  const consoleMsg = npmPackage + ': ' +
    path.relative(projectRoot, fileOriginFullPath) + ' -> ' +
    path.relative(projectRoot, fileDestFullPath)
  console.log(twoSpaces + consoleMsg)
}
```

As you can see in this file I am copying jquery and bootsrap files using a function `copyFile` with this syntax:

```js
copyFile(
  '<npmPackageName>',
  '<path/of/originFile/relative/to/packageDir>',
  '<path/to/destFile/relative/to/wwwDir>'
)
```

I use this in all my cordova projects and it works like a charm. That's how I see it

[image]

The hook is also triggered upon `cordova build` because `cordova build` equals to `cordova prepare && cordova compile`.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to use these node modules in Cordova without copying them into the www directory?

No, not easily: the contents of the `www` directory gets deployed to the native platform project by Cordova, unless explicitly copied by a hook script.

You could copy/symlink them into the `www` folder manually or use a hook script to automate this.

Comment: check this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm